# Backbone, Marionette - synchronous execution

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a function in my marionette LayoutView that has the following ui and events blocks:

```
 ui: {
        runAction: ".picasso-form-action-run"
 },

 events: {
        "click @ui.runAction": "runFilter"
 },
```

The runFilter function looks like this:

```
runFilter: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var _this = this;

        _this.ui.runAction.addClass('processing');
        _this.ui.runAction.text('Processing');
        _this.ui.runAction.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        setTimeout(function() {
            _this.trigger("whiteboard:data:refresh"); // this fetch data
        }, 5);
    }
```

My question is, I need to change the runAction button's text before I fetch new data, but the only way I can get this to work is to add a timeout to the trigger. This seems like a hack and would like to know what is the right way to do this.

The object that listens to the trigger, loads new data from the DB and renders a region.

Any help please.

Comment: Well in the above code, buttons text should change before triggering the event to fetch data... What's the need of timeout here..?

Comment: That is my issue, the button's text does not change. only once I added the timeout did it change.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]..?

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

This is probably because you are submitting a button which would submit and reload the page. Try to define the button with type="button" like this:

```
<button id="myButton" type="button" />
```

This prevents you from catching the event which is refreshing the page and will hopefully render what you wanted.